# How to create an overlay div using CSS only (no Javascript)?

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to create a div that overlays the page, staying in one place when the page scrolls, such as used in this article: [Top 5 Botched PC Game Launches](http://www.1up.com/do/feature?cId=3166996). (You will see a bar at the top that doesn't move, with the logo, *where gamers call home*).

I'm not even sure what the correct terminology is - it's probably not overlay :) But whatever it is, it appears to be done with CSS only, as it shows up when Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#status-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 19px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2147483646;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #8a8a8a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #8a8a8a;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #8a8a8a;
  background: transparent url("/images/Elements/status-bar/status-bar-bg.png") repeat-x;
}
```

Page source.

Related reading: [CSS Positioning 101 at A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)

Comment: Thanks, so the key is position:fixed. Is the z-index really necessary, or did that come from the sample page? Also, is there any specific *terminology* for that technique (like overlay or something)?

Comment: z-index is necessary to keep stacking order. But the value don't need to be so high, just high enough to keep element into top of others (which usually have z-index 1). I don't know a specific name to this technique.

Comment: Ok, you can set high z-indexes... But 2147483646?!

Comment: @bjb568 that is the highest possible z-index. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index

Comment: @karancan Isn't 3 enough? :P

Answer (score 1):

Little word of warning. If for some reason (I'm hoping IE6 gets fully deprecated) you have a real need to support IE6, that browser does not support position:fixed. You might want to use the "_" css property hack to just make it position absolute ( _position:absolute; )  for the case of IE6. Some other properties tweaking might be needed to look similar to non IE6 versions, and to behave in a way that at least is ok to go.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only concerned with modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code

```
.picColor{
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    background: url(img/flower.png) no-repeat;
    border:5px solid #000000;
}
.picColor:hover
{
    opacity:0.9;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
}
```

Full Source...[CSS Overlay](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/overlay.html)

Justin